# How can I view record-level TTLs in Windows Server 2003 DNS Application?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

As related in [another question](https://serverfault.com/questions/22176/need-help-understanding-windows-dns-dhcp-and-dynamic-ptrs), I have an issue with a AD server that has multiple PTR records for the same zone with different TTLs.  I can see this when doing a manual axfr of the zone:

```
ns1 0 /home/jj33 ># xfer 37.19.172.in-addr.arpa ad-dns | grep '^3\.'                  <
3.37.19.172.in-addr.arpa.       900     IN      PTR     0509-l3-tmbxt.example.ad.
3.37.19.172.in-addr.arpa.       1200    IN      PTR     0402-3p2jf41.example.ad.
```

Unfortunately, I can't find any button to push in the Windows GUI to see that these records have different TTLs.  Anyone know how to do this, or am I out of luck?

EDIT: The answer is Evan's response below but to summarize here: "Turn on View / Advanced".  Doh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TTL is in the "Properties" sheet for each individual record in W2K3 DNS. I'm sure it's in a similar place in W2K8 and W2K DNS. Unfortunately, you'll have to examine this on a record-for-record basis. There's no way to add TTL to the columns listed in the GUI.

Comment: I'm slow but I'm not that slow =).  There's no TTL in the RR properties tab in the tool I'm using, which I now see is called "dnsmgmt".  Should I be using another tool, or is there a "show me all the good stuff" option I can check?  Stepping away from PC right now, will post screen cap of the TTL-free properties panel later if you want

Comment: Go to View, then check Advanced

Comment: Thanks Evan.  Now I need to go see what other goodies I was missing by not having that turned on...